# fetch woocommerce product with custom taxonomy

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to create a custom category   for woocommerce product.Then I want fetch data of particular category.here is my taxonomy code,

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy

    add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_Item' );
    function custom_taxonomy_Item()  {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Items',
        'singular_name'              => 'Item',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Item',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Items',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Item',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Item:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Item Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Item',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Item',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Item',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Item with commas',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Items',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Items',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Items',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'item', 'product', $args );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'item', 'product' );
    }
```

After this I am creating a custom taxonomy template "taxonomy-product_cat-Item.php  " In my theme woo-commerce directory .After this I am unable to fetch data of particular category . honestly I have no idea how to do this .Any Help

Answer (score 1):

Your template name should be: `taxonomy-item.php`.
It should be taxonomy slug, without `product-cat`.

Comment: Aniruddha Gawade@in woo-commerce directory or in theme directory

Comment: Try putting it in Theme directory.

Comment: Aniruddha Gawade@taxonomy-product_cat-Item.php this is working .

Comment: On your template print `get_queried_object` to check if proper tax is selected.

Comment: Aniruddha Gawade@problem is that I am not able to crate custom template  for product custom taxonomy is " taxonomy-item.php"  and taxonomy-product_cat-Item.php not working

Comment: Not sure I understand.